# space at the end of variable is killed on output

Tags: linux, bash

I'm on `Ubuntu 12.04` with `bash 4.2.25(1)-release`. If I use

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n 'test ' > text;
echo 'test2' >> text;
```

everything works fine and the output of `text` is `test test2`. But if I use

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST='test ';
echo -n $TEST > text;
echo 'test2' >> text;
```

the space at the end of `$TEST` is removed and `text` contains `testtest2`.

Why? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ever so often, the answer lies in quoting.

```
echo -n $TEST > text
```

This will get expanded to:

```
echo -n test  > text
```

Note the two spaces after `test`. The only arguments `echo` sees are `-n` and `test`. Nothing else. The space gets lost here. To keep it, you need to double-quote `$TEST`:

```
echo -n "$TEST" > text
```

See also: [Quotes and escaping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#weak_quoting) on the Bash Hackers wiki.

Comment: Sure thing! I was just confused because your first example had `echo -n 'test'` before your edit. Note that it's a good habit to double-quote every variable where you want it substituted. You'll run in fewer issues most of the time, and there are only rare occasions where you'd actually want it expanded by the shell.